# How to add attribute maps of different types?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, dynamic-typing

Here's a C++(11) design problem:

Suppose I want to create a graph data structure, where you can map the nodes/edges to arbitrary attributes. (It's not really relevant that it's a graph, it might be any container for elements with attributes, but this is my example.)

With such a data structure, I could add a new attribute for all nodes dynamically:

```
Graph G;

G.addNodeMap("color", "white"); // map name, default value
```

... and then set it for a node:

```
node v;
G.setAttr("color", v, "blue");
```

... and also remove the attribute to save memory:

```
G.deleteNodeMap("color");
```

`G.addNodeMap` takes an identifier for the map (possibly a string) and a default value for the entries. With C++11, type `T` of the "node map" could be conveniently inferred from the default argument given. The node map itself could be a `std::vector<T>` because a node is just an index.

Problem: Where do I store the vectors `std::vector<std::string> map1`, `std::vector<std::double> map2`, `std::vector<Foo> map3`.... ?

This problem does not occurr with dynamically typed languages. How can I implement this behavior with C++?

Comment: It would generally be far more trouble than it's worth to make this work with arbitrary types. You'll have to get into some serious type-erasure.

Comment: @NicolBolas So what are alternatives for storing such attributes?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind currently is boost::any

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at property maps of the [**Boost.Graph Library**](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/using_property_maps.html) (BGL)

> The main link between the abstract mathematical nature of graphs and
>   the concrete problems they are used to solve is the properties that
>   are attached to the vertices and edges of a graph, things like
>   distance, capacity, weight, color, etc. There are many ways to attach
>   properties to graph in terms of data-structure implementation, but
>   graph algorithms should not have to deal with the implementation
>   details of the properties. The property map interface defined in
>   Section Property Map Concepts provides a generic method for accessing
>   properties from graphs. This is the interface used in the BGL
>   algorithms to access properties.